# Type B Nerve fibres cause exactly what kind of autonomic sensation to the preganglionic neurons?

Tags: neurophysiology, human-physiology

Ganong's Review of Medical Physiology (25th ed) presents the Erlanger and Gasser classification of mammalian Nerve Fibres as such:

[image]

Type B Fibres are concerned with Preganglionic autonomic sensations, but there is no mention of this being *sympathetic* or *parasympathetic*. Does it mean that it is both?
The table does specify it as *sympathetic* for the Type C Fibres, though.
(I have tried searching this on google, but I can't seem to find anything specific.)